# Select Tab on Page Load in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I have two tabs on a Razor page, I want to be able to load the page and either select page A or B. Currently, the page loads and always lands on A. I have attempted to do this as follows...

In my home view I call my products view

```
<a class="btn btn-default"
   href='@Url.Action("Index", "Products", new { id = "productB" })'
   role="button">
   Learn More 
</a>
```

where I am passing the route value "productB" so I can attempt to load the tab. In my products controller I have

```
public ActionResult Index(object id = null)
{
    if (id != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty())
        ViewBag.ActiveTab = id.ToString();
    return View();
}
```

products view

```
@{
    string activeTab = ViewBag.ActiveTab;
}

<div class="products container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#productA">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>productA
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#productB">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span>productB
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="products-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="productA" class="tab-pane active fade in">
                ...
            </div>
            <div id="productB" class="tab-pane fade">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the function

```
$(function () {
    var selector = '@activeTab';
    $("#" + selector).addClass("active");

    // Also tried the following...
    // var anchor = '@activeTab' || $("a[data-toggle=tab]").first().attr("href");
    // $('a[href=' + anchor + ']').tab('show');
});
```

But this does not select my tab page. This seems so simple, how can I get this to work?

Comment: The `a` does not have an `id="A"`

Comment: Okay, I used "A" and "B" for ease, but I suppose it is not realistic. The id of the tabs are set correctly.

Comment: Have you checked the value of "selector" in your JS. Try using '@ViewBag.ActiveTab' instead of '@activeTab' and make sure this called on load.

Comment: Where is html with tag who has an id?

Comment: I will add the HTML now...

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I have edited the question.

Comment: Have you verified in the rendered HTML that `var selector = '@activeTab';` becomes `var selector = 'productA';` or whatever? (Which BTW is absolutely an [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) vuln.) Have you also verified that you do not have any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap tabs?

Comment: Yes I am using bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    var anchor = "@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(activeTab))"
        || $(".nav-tabs a").first().attr("href").replace('#','');
    //$('#'+anchor).tab('show');
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#' + anchor + ']').tab('show');
});
```

Also ensure that you have [activated the tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

```
$('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
})
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aa7rwude/3/)

Comment: I'm not on board with your first snippet but the second is right from bootstrap's docs, and I feel like the first should also come from the docs, which would end up being something like `$('#@activeTab').tab('show');`.

Comment: Yes, that's the documentation way. I updated my answer.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your answer to take into account XSS?

Comment: I have checked my javascript, stepped through and it gets the correct tab elem, but it does not updated the view. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Killercam I'd suggest doing this without the ViewBag variable or any MVC framework pieces. Just call $("#productA").tab("show") and $("productB").tab("show") directly. It is sounding like you issue is with your JavaScript or HTML, and not MVC or Razor. Go setup a https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yes, if I click the tab changes fine.

Comment: I have some java script that restores tabs when the user refreshes and/or presses the back or forward nav browser buttons and this works too. I can add this to the question if you think it will help?

Comment: Nobody noticed, but you have to call .tab() method over the anchor not over the div. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should change the argument type from object to string. If you keep that as object , When you read it in your razor view from ViewBag, you are not going to get the string you expected (A or B), instead you are going to get `System.Object`

```
public ActionResult Index(string id = null)
{
    if (id != null)
        ViewBag.ActiveTab = id.ToString();
    return View();
}
```

Also, You should enable a tab by calling the tab method on the anchor tag for that tab. I changed your markup to include an Id for each anchor tag so that we can select the element in our jQuery code later.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" id="link-tabA" href="#productA">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>productA
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" id="link-tabB" href="#productB">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span>productB
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now in your document ready, use the value of `@activeTab` variable value (Which you read from your ViewBag already) to build the jQuery selector expression of the a tag and call the show method on that.

```
$(function () {
    var selector = '@activeTab';
    if(selector)
    {
       $("#link-tab"+selector).tab('show');
    }        
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I am sending the correct string, I just provided "A" as an illustration. I have updated the answer. I have also amended the id type still no selection...

Comment: The above code should work fine to add the css class to selected tab. ( Test it by adding a background color to your `active` css class and you can see the change in your page. I guess your problem is with the tab plugin ?

Comment: I have checked the JS and it steps through fine and get the right elem, the view is just not updated... Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @Killercam  See my updated answer. this is a working solution, tested in my local :)